# Error on CrudRepository. Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-2

I have an error that I cannot resolve in Spring boot 2.2.2 with my repository. This is a simple CRUD application using spring boot 2 with JPA MySQL and Web-Starter.

The error is:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Dec 16 10:03:20 GMT+01:00 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Invoked method public abstract java.lang.Iterable org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.findAll() is no accessor method!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invoked method public abstract java.lang.Iterable org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.findAll() is no accessor method!
    at org.springframework.data.projection.Accessor.<init>(Accessor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.MapAccessingMethodInterceptor.invoke(MapAccessingMethodInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectingMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProjectingMethodInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.ProxyProjectionFactory$TargetAwareMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProxyProjectionFactory.java:245)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.beroots.weblab2.controllers.TodoController.tplTodos(TodoController.java:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

My repository :

```
package com.beroots.weblab2.dao;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.beroots.weblab2.entities.Todo;

public interface TodoRepository extends CrudRepository<Todo, Long> {
    List<Todo> findByName(String name);
    List<Todo> findByCategory(String category);
    List<Todo> findByDescription(String description);
    List<Todo> findByDueDate(Date dueDate);
    List<Todo> findByCreateDate(Date createDate);
    List<Todo> findByState(boolean state);
}
```

And my controller:

```
package com.beroots.weblab2.controllers;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.beroots.weblab2.controllers.exceptions.HashGenerationException;
import com.beroots.weblab2.dao.TodoRepository;
import com.beroots.weblab2.entities.Todo;

@Controller
public class TodoController {

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    private TodoRepository todoRepository;

    // --------------------------------------
    @RequestMapping(value = "/todos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String tplTodos(Model model, TodoRepository todoRepository) {
        Iterable<Todo> todos = todoRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("todos", todos);
        return "v-todo-index";
    }
}
```

I do not understand why this error. My code seems correct ...

If someone has an idea ;)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your `TodoRepository` with `@Repository` and remove TodoRepository from the method parameter.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/todos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String tplTodos(Model model) {
    Iterable<Todo> todos = todoRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("todos", todos);
    return "v-todo-index";
}

@Repository
public interface TodoRepository extends CrudRepository<Todo, Long> {
List<Todo> findByName(String name);
List<Todo> findByCategory(String category);
List<Todo> findByDescription(String description);
List<Todo> findByDueDate(Date dueDate);
List<Todo> findByCreateDate(Date createDate);
List<Todo> findByState(boolean state);
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

First think first: 
How about you try constructor based injection. Since that is the preferred way of injecting anyway.

```
    private MessageSource messageSource;
    private TodoRepository todoRepository

    @Autowired
    public TodoController(MessageSource messageSource, TodoRepository todoRepository) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
        this.todoRepository = todoRepository;
    }
```

Second:

Why don't you add to your repo:

```
List<Todo> findAll();
```

Comment: Yes Sorry. I have remove the constructor in goals to make the controller lighter. But a bit lighter. lol

For the second point. I don't have a findAll definition in my repository because it is already defined by extending CrudRepository

But same error with this add